# Is it possible to access pi on my laptop through wifi?

Tags: wifi, headless, laptop

I can already set it up so that I can use the pi from my laptop through vncserver.

Obviously, an ethernet cable is needed to so this. I am trying to find out if it is possible to do a similar thing to that, but with the wifi instead of ethernet? In other words, can run on my laptop without hooking it up to an ethernet cable?

Just to clarify:
I am using rpi 2 B.

Also, when I set up the vnc server using the ethernet cable, I got the IP address for the IPv4 under the 'ethernet adapter ethernet' when entered the 'ipconfig' cmd in my laptop. To access the pi over wifi, would I have to use a different address?

Comment: What version of Raspberry Pi do you have? Going to assume its the 3 but just want to be sure.

Comment: *"Obviously, an ethernet cable is needed to so this."* -> If you mean you have been hooking the pi up directly to the laptop with an ethernet cable, no that is not necessary for anything.  It is just one way of establishing a connection, usually used if you have a pi with no wifi adapter and you do not want to/can't plug the pi into the router used by the laptop instead. **You need to clarify this because there are two very different questions you could be asking**; Patrick's is the correct answer to *one* of them.

Comment: Yes I have a wifi adapter, I'm now trying to connect to the pi through this and ditch the ethernet cable, which until now has been the only way I could connect. I'm not been able to successfully access it through the wifi however. Also, I have pi 2 B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pi (or any device for that matter) will get a different IP address for it's WiFi connection and ethernet connection by default (standard DHCP network), as both these interfaces will have a different MAC address and will look like different devices to your router. Run `ifconfig` on the Pi to get both IP addresses, and you may want to setup either a static IP for your PI or a DHCP reservation (also called static DHCP) on your router.

Comment: I have managed to connect through putty using wifi, however I have been unable to use the vnc viewer.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need to do anything different to use wifi. As long as you set up your wifi correctly, VNC and SSH will work exactly the same as they did with ethernet.

Comment: I can only assume my wifi has been set up properly, I've been able to connect using putty through the wifi. However I cannot seem to get into the vnc viewer with the ip address for the wifi

Answer (score 1):

well, if your Pi is already connected to your WiFi network and your laptop is also connected to the same WiFi, you can definitely connect with your Pi (given SSH is enabled, which usually IS by default)

You will just need to look for the IP of the pi, use any network scanner software to get the IP if you dont know it.

Then use PUTTY or other SSH terminal software to connect.

NETSCAN: https://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/

PUTTY: http://www.putty.org/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a correctly setup wi-fi dongle on Pi you can surely connect to it. 
The only thing you may want to check is if the Pi got an IPV6 address. That was what the case for me and spent a little bit of time trying to figuring out why I was non able to connect to my Pi. 
Just to be clear my Pi was connected to network only via Wifi

Comment: I'm able to connect to it over the wifi alone with putty, however I cannot get into with with the vnc viewer.

Comment: Mhh that seems odd... The only thing I could think of is if for some reason firewall block port used by vnc. However I should say that at least in my case that worked out by default without need to change firewall configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure what it was, any time I turned it on I'd get a prompt on my laptop saying another device had the same ip address. I just flashed raspian onto the card again and it worked first try after reinstalling it.

Comment: Well good you solved it ... :)